# Android app widget update based on contentprovider data change

Tags: android, android-widget, android-contentprovider

I am trying to add a widget to the launcher3 app that takes data from a contentprovider running in a separate process and displays it in a listview in the widget. The widget must update its listview items whenever the contentprovider data gets changed. I am looking for a few samples to understand how this works.Can someone point me to some links or samples for this?

Comment: Are you aware of how to basically update the view of a widget?

Comment: Yes, I am following the sample here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html but I need more details on how to do widget update when the contentprovider data changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually trigger an update. One way to do this is to send a broadcast intent to your `AppWidgetProvider`.

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String REFRESH_ACTION = "com.mypackage.appwidget.action.REFRESH";

    public static void sendRefreshBroadcast(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(REFRESH_ACTION);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class));
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (REFRESH_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // refresh all your widgets
            AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, ScheduleWidgetProvider.class);
            mgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(mgr.getAppWidgetIds(cn), R.id.widget_list);
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    ...
}
```

When data that is displayed by your app widget changes, your `ContentProvider` can simply call `MyAppWidgetProvider.sendRefreshBroadcast(getContext())`.